# Ordered groups - examples

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=BS(m,n)$ denote the [Baumslag–Solitar groups](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Baumslag%E2%80%93Solitar_group) defined by 
the presentation $\langle a,b: b^m a=a b^n\rangle$.

> Question: Find $m,n$ such that $G$ is an [ordered group](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Partially_ordered_group), i.e. $G$ is a group  on which a partial order relation $\le $ is given such that for any elements $x,y,z \in G$, from $x \le y$ it follows that $xz \le  yz$ and $zx \le  zy$.

Comment: Being an ordered group is a structure, not a property. The property is "can be given the structure of an ordered group."

Comment: Crossposted at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/128000/ordered-groups-examples

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_group):

A group $G$ is a partially ordered group if and only if there exists a subset $H\subset G$ such that:

i) $1 \in H$

ii) If $a ∈ H$ and $b ∈ H$ then $ab ∈ H$

iii) If $a ∈ H$ then $x^{-1}ax ∈ H$ for each $x\in G$

iv) If $a ∈ H$ and $a^{-1} ∈ H$ then $a=0$

---

For every $n,m$ can you find such a subset? Here's one thought: let $n=m=1$. Let $H=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb N\}$, where we include $a^0=1$. I believe this satisfies all the conditions and thus $G=BS(1,1)$ (which is the free abelian group on two generators) has a partial ordering.

Comment: Thanks. It is well known that the lattice $Z^n$ is a partially ordered group (the group operation is componentwise addition)

Comment: I am interested to know if G=BS(m,n) is an ordered group, assuming that G is non-abelian.

Comment: You should edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha:BS(m,n)\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be defined by $\alpha(a)=1,\alpha(b)=0$. Define a partial order on $BS(m,n)$ by $x\leq y$ if either $x=y$ or $\alpha(x)<\alpha(y)$. This partial order is bi-invariant.

The question of existence of a total ordering of $BS(m,n)$, either bi-invariant or left invariant, seems interesting.